# Creating multi-tiered dataframe - Rows & Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Is it possible to create a dataframe with multi-tiered columns and headers? Like this:

```
    C    bar    bar
    D    left   right
A   B           
foo up    1     2

foo down  3     4
```

where A & B are the column names that group foo & up / down, and C & D are the row names that group bar & left / right.

I can create the column multi-index no problem with `df.set_index(['A', 'B'])`, but then getting the `['C', 'D']` sorting across the rows is proving difficult.

The context is survey responses, where A = country, B = region; C = question response, D = preference. There are many groups within the C, so being able to group across the row with a subset of demographic per group is necessary.

---

Adding csv data sample per commenter request:

,,,,Question,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13
,,,,Answer,Total,Peru,Peru,Ecuador,Ecuador,Peru,Peru,Ecuador,Ecuador
,,,,Preference,Total,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2
Country,Region,Economy,Demographic,,,,,,,,,,
Brazil,Latin America,Non-OECD,Male,,249,7.20%,10.80%,12.00%,10.80%,15.70%,12.90%,12.00%,15.70%
Brazil,Latin America,Non-OECD,Female,,251,10.80%,10.00%,14.70%,15.50%,11.20%,13.10%,14.70%,11.20%
Brazil,Latin America,Non-OECD,18-24,,146,12.30%,10.30%,15.10%,15.10%,17.80%,16.40%,15.10%,17.80%
Brazil,Latin America,Non-OECD,25-44,,192,8.30%,13.00%,10.90%,13.50%,13.50%,13.50%,10.90%,13.50%
Brazil,Latin America,Non-OECD,45+,,162,6.80%,7.40%,14.80%,11.10%,9.30%,9.30%,14.80%,9.30%
Argentina,Latin America,Non-OECD,Male,,271,7.70%,6.30%,8.50%,15.10%,12.50%,14.00%,8.50%,12.50%
Argentina,Latin America,Non-OECD,Female,,229,6.60%,8.30%,8.70%,15.30%,15.70%,13.10%,8.70%,15.70%
Argentina,Latin America,Non-OECD,18-24,,140,8.60%,10.70%,7.90%,22.10%,17.90%,10.70%,7.90%,17.90%
Argentina,Latin America,Non-OECD,25-44,,180,9.40%,6.10%,7.20%,16.70%,16.70%,18.30%,7.20%,16.70%
Argentina,Latin America,Non-OECD,45+,,180,3.90%,5.60%,10.60%,8.30%,8.30%,11.10%,10.60%,8.30%

Comment: Can you add the sample survey responses.

Comment: @Bharathshetty I've added a small snippet to my original question as csv. The problem I'm having is having the multi-tiered headers on each column while also being able to read in the multi-tiered index for the rows. I'm not sure if it's possible to do or not -- the alternative is to expand each answer and create a normal dataframe (ie put everything into its own column -- country, region, economy, demographic, question, answer, preference -> all in their own place.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.columns.levels[0].name = 'C'
df.columns.levels[1].name = 'D'
```